# Unknown Server tag when build ASP.NET project using TFS build

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tfs

When I try to build ASP.NET project using Using TFS. I show me the error unknown server tag. However It build and publish successfully at visual Studio.

Please give me any suggestion

Comment: Post stack trace. Some usercontrol or custom control reference seems to be missing or not loaded.

Comment: Project Is not reference any 3rd party Control. There is a folder (UserConrol) inside project which contain all usercontrol files

Comment: Post stack trace. Complete error information.

Comment: /ALIS/Accounting/Admin/Period.aspx (280): 
Unknown server tag 'uc1:UCDate'.Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

Comment: Do you have registration of usercontrol as - <%@ Register TagPrefix="myControl" Namespace="M.Web.Forms.Controls" Assembly="My.Web" %>
Note that assembly is important if controls are outside the current assembly.

Comment: Clearly there's a difference between your TFS build system and your local build system. Ensure that your MSBuild files are the same and have the same environment (env-variables, filesystem, etc).